# Mediator Helper class in Vb.net

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, linq

I'm looking at trying to implement a mediator helper class to facilitate the transfer of information between viewmodels.

Starting with the following in c#

```
static public class Mediator 
{ 
    static IDictionary<string, List<Action<object>>> pl_dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<object>>>(); 

    static public void Register(string token, Action<object> callback) 
    { 
        if (!pl_dict.ContainsKey(token)) 
        { 
            var list = new List<Action<object>>(); 
            list.Add(callback); 
            pl_dict.Add(token, list); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            bool found = false; 
            foreach (var item in pl_dict[token]) 
                if (item.Method.ToString() == callback.Method.ToString()) 
                    found = true; 
            if (!found) 
                pl_dict[token].Add(callback); 
        } 
    } 

    static public void Unregister(string token, Action<object> callback) 
    { 
        if (pl_dict.ContainsKey(token)) 
            pl_dict[token].Remove(callback); 
    } 

    static public void NotifyColleagues(string token, object args) 
    { 
        if (pl_dict.ContainsKey(token)) 
            foreach (var callback in pl_dict[token]) 
                callback(args); 
    } 
}
```

I end up with the following in vb (courtesy of telerik's online converter

```
Public NotInheritable Class Mediator
Private Sub New()
End Sub
Shared pl_dict As IDictionary(Of String, List(Of Action(Of Object))) = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Action(Of Object)))()

Public Shared Sub Register(token As String, callback As Action(Of Object))
    If Not pl_dict.ContainsKey(token) Then
        Dim list = New List(Of Action(Of Object))()
        list.Add(callback)
        pl_dict.Add(token, list)
    Else
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        For Each item As var In pl_dict(token)
            If item.Method.ToString() = callback.Method.ToString() Then
                found = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not found Then
            pl_dict(token).Add(callback)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Unregister(token As String, callback As Action(Of Object))
    If pl_dict.ContainsKey(token) Then
        pl_dict(token).Remove(callback)
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Sub NotifyColleagues(token As String, args As Object)
    If pl_dict.ContainsKey(token) Then
        For Each callback As var In pl_dict(token)
            callback(args)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The compiler doesn't like the two For Each <...> As var statements.  I'm assuming that this is linq c# style which has always been very difficult to translate with ease.  This one has me ostensibly because I'm still trying to fathom out the whole principle anyway.  Can anyone suggest a proper construct for the two lines in question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB, the equivalent of `var` is to simply declare the variable without specifying the type, for instance:

```
For Each callback In pl_dict(token)
    callback(args)
Next
```

However, in order for that to work, you need to have [`Option Infer On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx).  Alternatively, you could just specify the type of the iterator variable as whatever it actually is (in this case, `Action(Of Object)`), like this:

```
For Each callback As Action(Of Object) In pl_dict(token)
    callback(args)
Next
```